# How to use current date in mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, date, sql-date-functions

I have a database that contains a column with type - Date. I also have a query with the date inputted as static which works fine but I would like to use todays date in the query. any recommendations?

Query :

```
 $q = 'SELECT count(ID) as count FROM ORDER WHERE 
ASSIGN_TO ='.$db->qstr($person).' AND OPEN_DATE ='.$db->qstr('2014-05-14');
```

This currently displays count of items after 2014-05-14

Comment: try...`AND OPEN_DATE ='NOW()';` for date-time and `AND OPEN_DATE = CURDATE());` for today's date.

Comment: I've tried that but I am getting errors in console. Syntax error. unexpected T_STRING

Comment: that is because its an error in syntax and not query. Try echoing out the query and run it in your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `NOW()` function that returns the current date. To avoid skewed answered by hours/minutes/seconds, you can use `date` to extract the date part:

```
$q = 'SELECT count(ID) as count FROM ORDER WHERE 
ASSIGN_TO ='.$db->qstr($person).' AND DATE(OPEN_DATE) = DATE(NOW())';
```

Comment: @user3620142 what do you mean? Have you got a column that stores a timestamp?

Comment: yea I have another column that stores date in time stamp called INFO_DATE data - 1399757473

Comment: You can use [FROM_UNIXTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) to translate a unix timestamp to a date, and from there on, it's pretty much the same.

Comment: I tried this AND FROM_UNIXTIME(INFO_DATE) = DATE(NOW())'; but it is not working. any suggestion?

Comment: You're missing another truncation there: `AND DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(INFO_DATE)) = DATE(NOW())';